# Powershell Cleanup script. Excluded folder not being excluded

Tags: powershell

I wrote a simple script that will run as a scheduled task every weekend. This script cleans up files older than # days and you can give the name of a folder for exclusion as a parameter. This folder should not be cleaned up by the script. But somehow the script still deletes some files from the excluded folder. But in a strange way no files matching the conditions of the parameter.

For example I run the script to delete files older than 15 days and exclude the folder NOCLEANUP. but some files still get deleted from that folder, but there are still files older than 15 days in the NOCLEANUP folder.

Code below

Thanks in advance and apologies for the dirty code. Still new to PS.

```
Function CleanDir ($dir, $days, $exclude, $logpath)
{
$Limit = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$days)
$Path = $dir
#Folder to exclude
$ToExclude = $exclude
#Log location
$Log= $logpath 
$Testpath = Test-Path -PathType Container -Path $Log

if ($Testpath -ne $true)
{

New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $Log

} 

#Logs deleted files

cd $Log
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastwriteTime -lt $Limit } | Where-Object { $_.fullname -notmatch $ToExclude} | Where-Object { $_.fullname -notmatch '$RECYCLE.BIN'} | Out-File -FilePath CLEANUPLOG.TXT

# Delete files older than the $Limit.
Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force | Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer -and $_.LastwriteTime -lt $Limit } | Where-Object { $_.fullname -notlike $ToExclude} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

#Goes into every folder separately and deletes all empty subdirectorys without deleting the root folders.

$Folder = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Directory

$Folder.fullname | ForEach-Object  
{ 
                           Get-ChildItem -Path $_ -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $True} | Where-Object {$_.GetFiles().Count -eq 0} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse

} 
}
```

Comment: Any reason why you don't let Get-ChildItem do the exclude?

Comment: No particular reason other than lack of knowledge :)

Comment: Can you add Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Force -exclude $ToExclude as per @Joey comments?

Comment: Does that exclude files or folder?